# Puppeteer: waitForSelector works in local Docker container but times out when deployed on Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, puppeteer

I have built a nodeJS service that takes a screenshot of a Single Page Application using Puppeteer. When the SPA is finished loading, a `<div>` element is added to the DOM. I am trying to capture this in order to continue with the screenshot.

Each request to the service is executed in a new Puppeteer incognito context.

```
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
const page = await context.newPage();
```

I am adding some custom HTTP headers for Google authentification as the SPA is behind an Identity-Aware Proxy:

```
const auth = new GoogleAuth();
const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(process.env.AUDIENCE);
const headers = await client.getRequestHeaders(url);
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders(headers);
```

The rest of the code is as follows:

```
const response = await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 50000});
error.handleResponse(response, log);

// Now wait for the dom element marking the map finished loading
log.writeToConsole('Waiting for the #trigger-print selector');
await page.waitForSelector('#trigger-print', {timeout: 50000});
log.writeToConsole('Selector found!');
```

The web service containing this snippet is dockerised; when I run the image on my local machine (running MacOS 10.15.7) and use the web service, the selector is found.
However, when I deploy the same image in the cloud (Kubernetes workload or Google Could Run), `page.goto(url)` is successful but the `waitForSelector` function always times out.
In this case I capture `page.content()` and there is no `<div id=trigger_print>` element. It looks like the SPA stopped loading after `page.goto(url)` completed.

I am logging all requests and console output but nothing looks out of the ordinary. What I am missing, what could it be and/or how could I debug this?